# How to get Bytes from CMSampleBufferRef , To Send Over Network 

Tags: ios, video-capture, avfoundation, video-processing, core-video

Am Captuing video using AVFoundation frame work .With the help of Apple Documentation [http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_MediaCapture.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2)

**Now i did Following things**

1.Created `videoCaptureDevice`
  2.Created `AVCaptureDeviceInput` and set `videoCaptureDevice`
  3.Created `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and implemented Delegate
  4.Created `AVCaptureSession` - set input as AVCaptureDeviceInput and set output as AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

5.In AVCaptureVideoDataOutput Delegate method

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
```

i got CMSamplebuffer and Converted into UIImage And tested to print UIImageview using

```
[self.imageView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Every thing went well up to this........

MY Problem IS,
I need to send video frames through UDP Socket .even though following one is bad idea i tried ,UIImage to NSData and Send via UDP Pocket. BUt got so Delay in video Processing.Mostly problem because of UIImage to NSDate

So Please GIve me Solution For my  problem

1)Any way to convert CMSampleBUffer or CVImageBuffer to NSData ??
  2)Like Audio Queue Service and Queue for Video to store UIImage  and do  UIImage to NSDate
   And Sending ???

if am riding behind the Wrong Algorithm Please path me in write direction

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is code to get at the buffer. This code assumes a flat image (e.g. BGRA).

```
NSData* imageToBuffer( CMSampleBufferRef source) {
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(source);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    void *src_buff = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:src_buff length:bytesPerRow * height];

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    return [data autorelease];
}
```

A more efficient approach would be to use a NSMutableData or a buffer pool.

Sending a 480x360 image every second will require a 4.1Mbps connection assuming 3 color channels.

Comment: Thanks for your response . CVimagebuffer to NSdata is ok. I have one small doubt ,in receiver i Couldn't get back the CVimagebuffer,bcoz that need height,width separately and bytes per row too

Comment: You could send this in the data 'header' if you wanted. [width:16bits][height:16bits][sequence number:16bits][count:16bit][data fragment]. There are other problems with your setup. Even assuming a MTU of 1500 your images are going to be spread out over many UDP packets. You are going to lose packets given the bitrate you need. I suggest you use TCP. I can see no advantage to using UDP given you will not be able to push more then maybe 2 frames per second out of the phone over a LAN/Wifi (@480x360). And at this rate you need to care about a lost video data.

Comment: Alternatively you could send the video information ahead of time to the receiver, or in the first UDP packet. You will still need some way to identify image fragments.

Comment: How do you convert back to a image buffer?

Comment: This code is giving data length 3686400 . but image is just 3000

Comment: What do you mean image is just 3000? Do you mean just 3000 pixels in total? What format is the image (RGBA, YUV etc...)?

Comment: I mean when i  NSLog(@"%i",[data length]); Then its logging 3686400 always.

Comment: Using the above code to get NSData, how would you get back to CVImageBuffer by using CGImageCreate? I can't see the link. Or is there another way?

Comment: I am not sure. I would just use a CVPixelBuffer and copy the contents of the NSData over to the CVPixelBuffer.

Comment: @SteveMcFarlin how to get bytes from audio buffer?

Answer (score 2):

Use `CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer` to get `CVImageBufferRef` from the sample buffer, then get the bitmap data from it with `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress`. This avoids needlessly copying the image.

Comment: Thanks for Your reply .Already i used CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress but i can use that as bytes? and using that alone ,can i able to draw  image in receiver side???

Comment: Yes, those are bytes. There are CVPixelBufferGetHeight()*CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow() of them. And if you do it right, you'll be able to reconstruct the image at the other end.

Comment: Does this work the same for planar format?  Or does one need to use CVPixelBufferGetHeightOfPlane and CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane instead?

Comment: You should use the planar versions. Saves you decoding the CVPlanarPixelBufferInfo_YCbCrBiPlanar struct.